# How to Reload ListView with Custom Cursor Adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-cursoradapter

**What I Have**

I have got a List View with a Custom Cursor Adapter. It is placed in a Fragment.

When I click on a button for a particular item from the list view, he item gets deleted from the database.

**What I Want**

I want the list view to get reloaded or refreshed when this happens. I mean when the button is clicked and the entry gets deleted from the database.

How can I implement this. When I press the back button, I should not be taken to the previous state of the list. Please post some examples on how I can achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try restarting loader or `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: post the class where you implement the button click

Comment: @GokhanArik I did that actually. It fies its job but the problem is that when I press tge back button the previous state of the list view gets shown. How can I overcome this?

Comment: Can you post your code? You need to feed the listview with new data

Comment: You should look into cursorloaders and content providers, as they handle this functionality for you.  Also its a good practice to wrap you dbhelper in a content provider to hide the implementation.

Comment: @Gokhan Arik I would love to post the full code, but the Custom Cursor Adapter class is the core of my app and is over 600 lines. Can you please point how can I feed he listview with new data?

Comment: You don't have to post everything, post where you create your ListView, your Adapter, and your Loader methods maybe